# Writing wave equation for a wave in two different media

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment, interference

Consider a young's double slit set-up **in water**. Consider a point $p$ on the screen , such that $S_{2}P-S_{1}{P}=s$.
Then , Wave equation for wave from $S_{1}$ at point P: $Asin(2\pi/\lambda(x) -\omega t)$, and for the wave through $S_{2}$: $Asin(2\pi/\lambda(x+s) -\omega t)$=$Asin(2\pi/\lambda(x) -\omega t+ 2\pi/\lambda(s))$.

Clearly, the phase difference is $2\pi/\lambda(s)$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength in water.

Now suppose we introduce a glass slab, with refractive index $\mu$ in-front of $S_{1}$. The wave for the wave through S2 at point P will be the same. However, How will we write the equation for the wave through $S_{1}$, accounting for the fact that it has travelled through two different media?

Answer (score 0):

The wave through $S_{1}$ has traveled an extra optical path difference of $\delta x =  a.(\mu_2-\mu_1)$ where $a$ is the thickness of the slab, $\mu_2$ is the refractive index of the material of slab and refractive index of water is $\mu_1$.

Corresponding phase difference is $\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}.(\delta x)$. where $\lambda$ is wavelength of light in vacuum.

hence, equation of light through $S_{1}$ can be given by

$$E=E_o\sin(\omega t-\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(\mu_1x + a.(\mu_2-\mu_1)))$$
Where $x$ is the geometric distance of point $P$ from $S_1$

Comment: well, the point was that i wanted to find out the phase difference *from* the wave equation

Comment: the wave equation is $E=E_o\sin(\omega t-\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}("optical distance traveled"))$ so, if you put the new optical path expression in the parentheses you can get the phase difference from the equation.

Comment: any derivation/source for this comment?

Comment: i dont get what it is exactly that you are not getting. equation of a light wave is of the form $E=E_{o}\sin(\omega t - \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} x)$. $x$ is the distance along line of propagation of light. for info on optical path: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_path_length#Optical_path_difference)